# Root Controller UINavigationBar disappears after user logout with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uinavigationbar

I'm facing a slight problem with my UINavigationBar.

I have a an Initial Root View Controller (ViewController) followed by 2 View Controllers (LoginMRNViewController and LoginOTPViewController) that are used to login the user with One Time Password. I also have NavigationController used to navigate the user to his/her homepage after logging in. 
In the homepage, I have a (Logout) button, that logs out the user with Firebase and navigates him/her to the Initial Root View Controller (ViewController).

The UINavigationBar works like a charm, however, whenever the user logout, he is navigated to the Initial Root View Controller (ViewController) but the UINavigationBar completely disappears!

My logout function:

```
@IBAction func logoutPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLoginScreen", sender: self)
        print ("User logged out")
    } catch let error {
        print ("Failed to logout with error", error)
    }
}
```

Here's how my [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dfb0.png) looks like.

**EDIT:**

I tried to put this in my Initial Root View Controller (ViewController) and the other 2 View Controllers (LoginMRNViewController and LoginOTPViewController) in the ViewWillAppear method, but unfortunately it did not work.

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

Here's how my updated [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6riEZ.png) look like.

Comment: Why dd you put another navigation controller before the home view controller?

Comment: I added another Navigation Controller to remove the back button off the homepage, so the user is unable to go back to the login screen. I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but it worked for me.

Comment: That is not the right way. You should only have one navigation controller per app. I think your second navigation controller is what's causing the problem. Remove that navigation controller and only use the first one from now on. To hide the back button simply use "navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)"

Comment: I removed the second Navigation Controller and added the method, it hid the homepage back button. But unfortunately the UINavigationBar is still hidden after  the user logout!

Comment: Then try simply putting "self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)" in the viewWillAppear method of your Root VC.

Comment: I tried that, it did not work.

Comment: Even if it's not the right way to do it, did you try to put `tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false` in the ViewWillAppear of your login screen?

Comment: @schtipoun I tried this too, but no luck with it! As soon as the user logout the UINavigationBar disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the another NavigationController to hide back button.

Add `navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)` to hide back button.

Then on logout simply add `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

It should work as expected.

Comment: I did exactly like what you said, but now I ran into another problem where the logout button does not navigate the user to the Initial Root View Controller.

Comment: @AseelM You mean to say logout doesn't navigate user to ViewController where you have LOGIN button?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean.

Comment: Are you pushing all the views [from first to dashboard] on the NavigationController? Or you are Presenting any?

Comment: Yes, all of my views are pushed on the NavigationController. I did not present any.